# In an MVC web.config file what does the setting compilation debug='true' do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, web-config

For performance reasons an MVC app should have compilation debug='false' set in its web.config.

What benefits does having it set to 'true' during development give? I know that it 'inserts debugging symbols into the compiled page' but what is that for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this quite interesting link](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/debug_code_in_production) (very old, but still pertaining), which tries to explain in more detail the workings of either compilation mode, or, at least contrast between them well.

In an attempt to directly answer your question regarding what debugging symbols are used for - these give extra information about the compiled code and allow for interrogation of the executing code-base when a debugger is attached; allowing you to step through the source, for instance, as the binary can now be mapped back to it's location in the source file, variable names etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is used for the code that is compiled on the fly (such as aspx and ascx pages) and will instruct the compiler how to compile the files.

Rest of the files such as models, global.asax, etc will be compiled to bin folder.